# add attribute in add new product genaral tab

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I have this error: Wrong attribute set ID , where is a problem

I tried this:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
Mage::log("other_setup_addAttribute UPGRADE 0.0.1 -> 0.0.2 START");

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$data=array(
    'type'=>'varchar',
    'input'=>'text',
    'sort_order'=> 7, //under visibility field
    'label'=>'Promotion %',
    'global'=>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'required'=>'0',
    'comparable'=>'0',
    'searchable'=>'0',
    'is_configurable'=>'1',
    'user_defined'=>'1',
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
    'unique'=> false
);

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product','sd_promotion_label',$data);

$attributeId= $setup->getAttribute('catalog_product','sd_promotion_label');


$setup->addAttributeToSet(
                          'catalog_product', 'Default', 'General', $attributeId
);

Mage::log("other_setup_addAttribute 0.0.1 -> 0.0.2 END");
$installer->endSetup();
```

**EDIT**

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
Mage::log("other_setup_addAttribute UPGRADE 0.0.2 -> 0.0.3 START");

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$data=array(
    'type'=>'varchar',
    'input'=>'text',
    'sort_order'=> 7, //under visibility field
    'label'=>'Promotion %',
    'global'=>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'required'=>'0',
    'comparable'=>'0',
    'searchable'=>'0',
    'is_configurable'=>'1',
    'user_defined'=>'1',
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
    'unique'=> false
);

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product','sd_promotion_label',$data);

$attributeId= $setup->getAttribute('catalog_product','sd_promotion_label');

$_attributeSetId = $setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product','Default');//default
$_attributeGroupId = $setup->getAttributeGroup('catalog_product',$_attributeSetId,'General'); //General

$setup->addAttributeToSet(
    'catalog_product', $_attributeSetId, $_attributeGroupId, $attributeId
);

Mage::log("other_setup_addAttribute 0.0.2 -> 0.0.3 END");
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of the error, magento tries to get the id of the "Default" attribute while it does not exist !

`$_attributeSetId = $setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product','Default');` <- this one.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass the name of the attribute set ID and attribute group ID instead of the ID itself. Look up the ID first before trying to add it like this:

```
$_attributeSetId = $setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product','Default');
$_attributeGroupId = $setup->getAttributeGroup('catalog_product',$_attributeSetId,'General');
```

Replace your `addAttributeToSet` with this:

```
$setup->addAttributeToSet(
                          'catalog_product', $_attributeSetId, $_attributeGroupId, $attributeId
);
```

Comment: I have the same error: Wrong attribute set ID

Comment: This is not a really solution but +1 for your effort seanbreeden